# php only show request_method as get

Tags: php

I am trying to log some request in php. I just want to check it it is get or post.

```
$request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

if($request_method != 'get' && $request_method != 'post') {
    return $request_method;
}

if($request_method == 'post' && isset($_POST['_method'])) {
    return strtolower($_POST['_method']);
}

echo($request_method);
```

This always return `get`. Please see my postman screeneshot [image]

Comment: Keep in mind that Postman raw body must be read from `php://input` and not from `$_POST`

Comment: Can you show actual result from `var_dump($request_method)`

Comment: What are you `return`ing from?  If you just want to check request method just `print_r($_SERVER)`?

Comment: If the request method is GET when doing a POST, make sure that the web server doesn't redirect calls to `/contact` to something like `/contact/`. This is usually a setting in the web server. If that happens (with the response code 302), the redirect will make a GET request to the new URL. If that is the case, it should work if you change the redirect from 302 to 307 (which is a redirect that tells the client the new URL and that they should use the same request method).

Comment: @Justinas,  the result is  string(3) "get"

Comment: OK, its the problem with /contacts, it needs to be /contacts/,  thanks @MagnusEriksson